# Is there a formula to find a specific number within a cell?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find a specific identification number within a cell. The problem is that each cell containing such number has others too separated by a semi colon...
I want to have the same results as if using lookup (not sure if it's possible). 
The end result is to have the cost associated to each id number, that in turns is related to a specific order. [image: Cell 4A contains the info I'm looking for]
 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you can get the location of a number with `FIND`. The formulas in `D2` and `D3` are what is located in cells `C2` and `C3`, respectively.

[image: Excel]

Comment: Dear JasonAizkalns, Thanks for your answer, but I couldn't make it work yet. Maybe I should have mention that the reference value i'm looking for is in another spreadsheet, that is Spreadsheet 1 has the number 123 in cell A1, so I need to find A1 from Spreadsheet 1 in to Spreadsheet 2. Moreover Spreadsheet 2  has a range of cell that contains a list of numbers as shown in the picture. Thanks again!